# RSPEC For Association in Active model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How to test the foreign key association in rspec,

Here is the code

```
has_one :store, :foreign_key => "seller_id", :class_name => "Store"
```

How to write rspec for this code

Please tell me some suggestion

Comment: You are trying to test basic Rails functionality - you shouldn't do that, focus instead on your specific application requirements. That said, @gayavat answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model.new.build_store.class.should eql Store

Comment: I think you mean `Store` (without quotes).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is shoulda-matchers gems. Check this out: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

```
describe Post do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should have_many(:tags).through(:taggings) }
end

describe User do
  it { should have_many(:posts) }
end
```